# Load local image into canvas without using file API

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating a javascript application that is communicating with a REST web server, to add an image I have to convert it to base64. To convert the image to base64 I was going to use canvas toDataUrl() but to load a local file I need to use the File API which is not that well supported (I need to support at least IE9). Is there a way how I can achieve this without using the file API and without using the server?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the File API when supported and fall back to [Flash Player](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Loading_a_local_file_to_a_byte_array_in_Flash_Play-16715.html) for browsers that don't support the File API.

It pretty easy to convert a ByteArray in Flash into a Base64 string. I usually use [com.sociodox.utils.Base64](http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html) because the encoding performance is great.